# Cómo ajustar un LEFT JOIN muy lento en mi consulta?

Tags: mysql

Buenos dias tengo 2 tablas

en la primera articulo tengo campos con codigos de la segunda tabla, en esta segunda tabla existe un campo codigo y nombre.

ejemplo:
a: primera tabla

nombrearticulo   codigo1 codigo2 codigo3 codigo4

b: segunda tabla

codigo   nombre

en esta nueva consulta que estoy tratando de realizar quiero que se una el nombre de la segunda tabla a los codigos de la segunda tabla que estan guardados en la primera tabla.

cabe mencionar que hay muchos campos que pueden estar vacios dentro de codigo1 puede haber codigo y en los 2,3 y 4 vacios o puede que los 4 campos esten ocupados, o solo dos.. etc.

quiero que aparezca asi:

nombrearticulo codigo1 codigo2 codigo3 codigo4   nombre1 nombre2 nombre3 nombre4

este es mi codigo pero el left join suele tardar demasiado, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
SELECT
    cod_art,
    nom_art,
    nom_art2,
    articulo.cod_uni,
    unidad.nom_uni,
    articulo.cod_sgrupo,
    articulo.cod_grupov,
    articulo.cod_area,
    nom_area,
    s1.nom_sgrupo,
    s2.nom_sgrupo AS nom_Grupov,
    factor_prod,
    tipo_articulo.esProduccion,
    articulo.cod_tart,
    nom_tart,
    es_pcosto,
    pre_costo,
    pre_prom,
    articulo.pre_venta,
    pre_inc_imp,
    afecto_igv,
    articulo.archivar,
    articulo.activo,
    obs,
    cod_artext,
    cod_artext1,
    cod_artext2,
    cod_artext3,
    cod_artExt4,
    articulo.b_ancho,
    articulo.b_alto,
    
        
    CASE WHEN articulo.cod_artExt = ot1.codigo THEN ot1.nombre ELSE NULL END As Nombre,
    CASE WHEN articulo.cod_artExt1 = ot2.codigo THEN ot2.nombre ELSE NULL END As Nombre2,
    CASE WHEN articulo.cod_artExt2 = ot3.codigo THEN ot3.nombre ELSE NULL END As Nombre3
    
    
FROM
    articulo
    INNER JOIN subGrupo s1 ON articulo.cod_sgrupo = s1.cod_sgrupo
    LEFT JOIN subgrupo s2 ON articulo.cod_grupov = s2.cod_sgrupo
    INNER JOIN unidad ON articulo.cod_uni = unidad.cod_uni
    INNER JOIN tipo_articulo ON articulo.cod_tart = tipo_articulo.cod_tart
    LEFT JOIN area ON articulo.cod_area = area.cod_area
    



LEFT JOIN micros_imp AS ot1 ON ot1.codigo = articulo.cod_artExt
LEFT JOIN micros_imp as ot2 ON ot2.codigo = articulo.cod_artExt1
LEFT JOIN micros_imp as ot3 ON ot3.codigo = articulo.cod_artExt2



    
WHERE
    ( s1.esProduccion OR s2.esVenta ) 
    

    
    AND articulo.activo = 1 
    AND articulo.archivar = 0 
    AND tipo_articulo.cod_tart BETWEEN 01 
    AND 09 
    AND articulo.cod_alma = "0002" 
GROUP BY
    articulo.nom_art 
ORDER BY
    nom_art ASC
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a LuciRofocale a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Es una consulta compleja con varios LEFT JOIN y no es claro dónde crees que está tu problema. La consulta _se ve_ correcta, pero no sabemos qué indices hay, cuántos datos tiene cada tabla, etc. Por qué dices que es lenta? Por favor, trata de editar tu pregunta y añadir información

Comment: Hola, por ejemplo los ultimos 3 left join a la misma tabla micros_imp que es la segunda tabla desde donde quiero obtener el nombre según el codigo guardado en la primera tabla articulo, borro un lef join osea solo me quedo con ot1 y ot2 demora 4 segundos en responder la consulta mostrandome el contenido. pero si lo dejo con los 3 join a la misma tabla ot1, ot2,ot3 demora 10 minutos en responder la consulta.

Comment: faltara algun indice y por eso tarda tanto la tercera? que pasa si pones esa sola? tarda tambien?

Comment: Sin conocer la estructura de las tablas, los CREATE TABLE y los índices que tienen, no hay forma de dar una respuesta.

Comment: es la misma tabla a la que se le hace left join varias veces ya que quiero que los nombres que estan almacenados en esa tabla me aparezcan en la nueva consulta. si solo coloco un solo left join osea por ejemplo esta tercera, solo tarda 4 segundos, incluso hasta con2 left join, pero cuando ya colocas 3 left join a la misma tabla es cuando comienza a demorarse entre 7 a 10 minutos.